# how to add a line break only using css without br tag

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, inline

```
<div id="auth_1" class="auth" style={{display:"flex"}} >
    <div class="prefix">11</div>
    <div class="givenname">77</div>
    <div class="familyname">22</div>
    <div class="suffix">44</div>
    <div class="url">URL :66</div>
    <div class="phone">PHONE :33</div>
    <div class="fax">FAX :44</div>
 </div>
```

what i get:
11 77 22 44 URL :66 PHONE :33 FAX :44

what i need:

11 77 22 44

URL :66 PHONE :33 FAX :44

Please help me in solving this .plz.

i tried

```
  .url:before {
  content: '\a';
  white-space: pre;
}
```

but no result.

Answer (score 1):

use double :: not : to CSS before

```css
.url::before {
  content: '\a';
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="auth_1" class="auth"  >
    <div class="prefix">11</div>
    <div class="givenname">77</div>
    <div class="familyname">22</div>
    <div class="suffix">44</div>
    <div class="a url">URL :66</div>
    <div class="phone">PHONE :33</div>
    <div class="fax">FAX :44</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: still no result bro.

Comment: Can you remove display flex from style and try  @Yadharth

Comment: I removed flex and used inline-block for every child element. but I can't get the necessary result bro.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use the div to wrap items which are needed in a single row and apply flex and 
flex direction property to make them stay in a single row.

At Outer div apply flex direction as column to keep all items in a column.         

     <div
      id="auth_1"
      class="auth"
      style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}
     >
      <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <div className="prefix">11</div>
        <div className="givenname">77</div>
        <div className="familyname">22</div>
        <div className="suffix">44</div>
      </div>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <div className="url">URL :66</div>
        <div className="phone">PHONE :33</div>
        <div className="fax">FAX :44</div>
      </div>
    </div>

I hope it solved you issue and gave your required output!
```

Comment: Also you can use gap property of flexbox, to give the spacing between the flex items. Check how to use gap property here - https://coryrylan.com/blog/css-gap-space-with-flexbox

Answer (score 0):

You can use this property in css:-

content: '\a';

Please [check](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-add-a-line-break-using-css) this link for how to use it.

Comment: Please use the code formatting when answering, and also explain in the post. This is helpful for search engines, scrapers, and also people with millions of tabs, like me.